# reading regex from xsd file with xpath, string value

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xsd

I've got an XSD file with such element:

```
<xs:element name="orcid" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="https://orcid\.org/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-\d{3}[\dX]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I'd like to read the pattern from that value and I do:

```
with open(app.config.get("schema")) as xsd:
  doc = etree.parse(xsd)
  data = doc.xpath(ORCID_XPATH, namespaces=doc.getroot().nsmap)[0]
```

where

```
ORCID_XPATH = '/xs:element/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction[@base="xs:string"]/xs:pattern/@value
```

but as a result I got a string I don't understand:

```
'[d0-9]{4}-{0,1}[0-9]{3}[0-9xX]{1}'
```

Could you please explain to me what's happening here?

Comment: What's your input XML?

Comment: The important fragment is above. The element is found well, that's what I am sure of. It's just the value that got mixed up for some reason.

Comment: You're probably selecting the first applicable xs:element instead of the one you really want. Try this instead: `ORCID_XPATH = '/xs:element[@name="orcid"]/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction[@base="xs:string"]/xs:pattern/@value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path expression isn't very selective, in particular it doesn't qualify `xs:element` with `[@name='orcid']`. So I suspect you're picking up a different element declaration. Since you're in Python, you're probably using XPath 1.0, which typically gives you the first matching node, rather than warning you that there's more than one.